# Can't connect Samsung S7 to Mac

Tags: samsung, macos, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

Basically I'm trying to run my application on a Samsung S7 but my Mac isn't recognizing the device. I've tried installing Android File Transfer and it doesn't recognize it either. USB Debugging is enabled as well. Any ideas? The device OS is 6.0.1.

Comment: Try disabling USB debugging. Also try toggling between MTP and PTP modes while connected.

Comment: Try installing [Kies](http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/).

Comment: @MatthewRead AFAIK Kies has been replaced by Smart Switch. At least my last Kies installation has asked me to update to that.

Comment: @GiantTree That explains why I was getting redirected to [Smart Switch](http://www.samsung.com/us/smart-switch/) when trying to find Kies.  Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewRead Kies didn't work but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings -> SYSTEM(last tab in settings) -> About Device ->Tap on " Build Number" 7 times, this will enable developer mode.
Go back one screen and you have a new menu option for "Developer Option" tap that and turn on USB debugging.

Google for "Android File Transfer". Install and open the app, connect your phone to the mac.

a directory browser will show up and copying files is as easy and drag and drop.

Comment: I would like to drop my comment that needing to grant permission for debugging process (a popup will appear)

Answer (score 0):

After you download Kies, use the uninstall part of the software to remove all the Kies drivers (which SmartSwitch uses), restart and then Android File Transfer will work.

Remember to unlock your phone and enable the USB for MTP.